# Rails : Combining scopes with OR instead of AND

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 named scopes :

```
scope :by_calls, ->  {where.not(call_id: nil)}
scope :by_meetings, ->  {where.not(meeting_id: nil)}
```

And in the future, I will add more types like by_events, by_emails etc and try to filter by one or more of them

Is there a way how I can easily chain these scopes by OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did :

```
scope :interaction_type_filter, lambda {|interaction_type|
    allowed_values = ['call', 'meeting']
    return nil if interaction_type.blank?
    sql_statement = interaction_type.first+'_id IS NOT NULL '
    interaction_type.shift
    interaction_type.each do |type|
        if allowed_values.include? type
            sql_statement += 'OR '+type+'_id IS NOT NULL'
        end
    end 
    where(sql_statement)
}
```

Hence I can now check for nil within an array of given columns

Answer (score 0):

Use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel):

```
model = Model.arel_table
model.where(model[:call_id].eq(nil)).or(model[:meeting_id].eq(nil))
```

Just change `Model` to the name of the model which contains those scopes.